# How do I make one item in a list == to an item in another list?

Tags: python, list

For example, I am trying to be able to have the user input a province like "alberta" and then have it display "AB" to the user. Or the other way around. I can only use lists. (The instructor mention something about "parallel lists"?)

This is what I tried...

```
def lists (province, abrev):
    userInput = input("Enter Province or Abreviation: ")
    province = ["alberta", "nova scotia", "british columbia"]
    abrev = ["AB", "NS", "BC"]
    for ab in range(len(province)):
        if province["alberta"] == abrev["AB"]:
        print("AB")
    if userInput == province:
        print(len(province))
def main():

    lists()

main()
```

Comment: Hint: you should probably be using the `ab` variable somewhere in your loop.

Comment: You are also not accessing your elements in the list properly. Remember, list access requires an integer value.

Comment: @idjaw I believe I know what you mean, how do I call my list() function properly in main()?

Comment: Have you learned about the `zip` function yet? It's perfect when you need to process 2 (or more) lists in parallel. But if you don't know `zip` there are other ways.

Comment: @PM2Ring No he hasn't said anything about zip yet, I'll have to look into it myself

Comment: See my answer for use of `zip`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use zip() to join two lists together.

```
province = ["alberta", "nova scotia", "british columbia"]
abrev = ["AB", "NS", "BC"]

userInput = input("Enter Province or Abreviation: ")

for prov,ab in zip(province,abrev):
    if userInput == prov:
        print(ab)
    elif userInput == ab:
        print(prov)
```

Alternatively you can use dictionaries. With this method you have a key and a value

```
province_dict = {'NS': 'nova scotia', 'BC': 'british columbia', 'AB': 'alberta'}
```

If you want to lookup what state has the abbreviation 'AB' then you would do

```
print(province_dict['AB'])
```

Since you are dealing with user input you should use

```
province_dict.get(userInput,'Unknown')
```

This will return 'Unknown' if the item is not found in the dictionary rather than raising a KeyError.

Comment: How could I connect the dictionary to userInput?

Comment: Simplest way is `print(province_dict[userInput])`

Comment: However since you are dealing with humans who might not type in a valid value. I'd suggest `province_dict.get(userInput,'Unknown')`. This will return 'Unknown' if the item isn't found in the dictionary rather than raise a KeyError

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `index()` method on lists, you shouldn't have to loop over all of the elements.